# Alloy and require external JS

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

Right now I have a function in my `alloy.js` file that is a global.

```
Alloy.Globals.indicator = function(parent)
{
  var view = Ti.UI.createView({
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    backgroundColor: '#000',
    opacity: 0.6,
    visible: false
  });

  function osIndicatorStyle()
  {
    style = Ti.UI.iPhone.ActivityIndicatorStyle.PLAIN;
    if ('iPhone OS' !== Ti.Platform.name) style = Ti.UI.ActivityIndicatorStyle.DARK;
    return style;
  };

  var activityIndicator = Ti.UI.createActivityIndicator({
    style: osIndicatorStyle(),
    height: Ti.UI.FILL,
    width: 100
  });

  view.add(activityIndicator);
  parent.add(view);

  function openIndicator()
  {
    view.visible = true;
    activityIndicator.show();
  }

  view.openIndicator = openIndicator;

  function closeIndicator()
  {
    activityIndicator.hide();
    view.visible = false;
  }

  view.closeIndicator = closeIndicator;
  return view;
};
```

I'd rather not have this large function as a global and instead import it to the files I need using `require`.

I have searched and cannot figure out first, where to place this file and second how to actually "require" it.

All this simply does is create a view that acts as a modal view with a activity indicator. The function also includes two function to show and hide it.

Comment: You should create a `widget` for something like this. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Alloy.Widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a folder called "lib" inside the "app" folder.

Inside this folder, make a file called whatever you like e.g. functions.js:

```
var functionName = function(){
     //your function code here
}
exports.functionName = functionName;
```

In your controller:

```
var functions = require('functions');
functions.functionName();
```

You might want to also look at [Widgets](http://www.slideshare.net/MartinHudson1/ticonfeu) which are re-usable components complete with view/controller/styles as I think this would fit your requirement slightly better.

[Link to docs](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium)

Comment: Thanks Phil. I will take a look at the widgets, but it looks like either of these will work.

Comment: yep both will work, using Widgets just means you get a better structure (XML for the View etc...)